# How does CompareTo sort a list?

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, compareto

Below, a list `l` that contains a list of `Product` with `Name` and `Price` properties.
The list can be sort alphabetically by the following class `ProductNameComparer` which implements **IComparar**.

```
List<Product> l = p.GetList();
l.Sort(new ProductNameComparer());
MessageBox.Show(l[0].Name);

public class ProductNameComparer : IComparer<Product>
{
    public int Compare(Product x, Product y)
    {
        return x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name);
    }
}
```

I do not understand how the list is being sorted. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto.aspx) `CompareTo` returns an **Int32** type value of **less than zero**, **zero**, or **greater than zero**. If I have:

```
string c = "Apple";
string d = "Orange";
return c.CompareTo(d)
```

The function will return "**-1**".

But if I replace `l.Sort(-1)` instead of `l.Sort(new ProductNameComparer())` the code doesn't compile

Also why would `Compare(Product x, Product y)` takes only two Products as argument and yet managed to compare and sort a list (>2) of products?

Comment: You have two questions here. Do you already understand the basics of sorting algorithms like QuickSort, MergeSort, Insertion Sort?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `Sort` method doesn't just call `Compare` once - it calls it multiple times, whenever it needs to compare two items. It's a general sort algorithm which is able to sort any collection of items, so long as it can compare any two of them in a consistent way.

The code doesn't compile if you try to call `l.Sort(-1)` because that's just trying to pass in an integer - what would that even mean?

You need to understand that you're not giving the `Sort` method *one comparison result* - you're giving it the ability to compare whichever items it needs to.

Answer (score 7):

For the purpose of demonstration here is a possible implementation of the Sort method (a highly inefficient one, I know):

```
public void Sort(System.Collections.Generic.IComparer<T> comparer)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < this.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < this.Count; j++)
        {
            if (comparer.Compare(this[i], this[j]) > 0)
            {
                T tmp = this[i];
                this[i] = this[j];
                this[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Sort method overload used in your example (`new ProductNameComparer()`) requires the parameter to implement an [IComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s.aspx) interface. Calling `Sort(-1)` won't work since int doesn't implement this interface. As per @JonSkeet, the result of calling `CompareTo()` is used by the sorting strategy to order the list.